# How do I properly test angular material components?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-material

I am trying to use `mat-error` and basically it just displays an error message if the field is null. I have tested it manually with `ng-serve` and it does work perfectly, but I'm having a hard time acquiring the html element when it appears. Here is what my code looks like:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input type="number" matInput placeholder="Gain or Loss" class="gain-or-loss-input-field" [formControlName]="'gainOrLoss'">
  <mat-error *ngIf="entryForm.controls.gainOrLoss.errors && entryForm.controls.gainOrLoss.errors.required"
             class="gain-or-loss-required-error-message">
    Gain or Loss is <strong>required</strong>.
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>

// other code here...

<button mat-raised-button color="primary" class="add-report-button" (click)="addEntry()">Add Report</button>
```

Here is what my test looks like:

```
  let component: AddReportModalComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AddReportModalComponent>;
  let pageDebug: DebugElement;
  let pageElement: HTMLElement;
  let entryService: EntryService;
  let entryServiceSpy: any;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    entryServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('EntryService', [
      'fetchEntriesByStartDateEndDateAndCompany',
      'addEntry'
    ]);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ AddReportModalComponent ],
      imports: [
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatDatepickerModule,
        MatOptionModule,
        MatSelectModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        MatNativeDateModule,
        MatInputModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: MatDialogRef, useValue:{}},
        { provide: EntryService, useValue: entryServiceSpy },
        { provide: DateService, useValue:{}}
      ],
      schemas: [
        CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA,
        NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
      ]
    }).compileComponents().then(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AddReportModalComponent);

      pageDebug = fixture.debugElement;
      pageElement = pageDebug.nativeElement;

      entryService = pageDebug.injector.get(EntryService);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;

      fixture.detectChanges();
    });
  }));

  it('should display an error message if Gain or Loss field is null when the form is submitted.', async(() => {
    component.entryForm.controls.gainOrLoss.setValue(null);

    const addReportButton = pageDebug.query(By.css(addReportButtonSelector));
    addReportButton.nativeElement.click();

    fixture.detectChanges();

    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      const requiredErrorElement = pageDebug.query(By.css('.gain-or-loss-required-error-message'));
      expect(requiredErrorElement.nativeElement.innerText).toEqual('Gain or Loss is required.');
    });

  }));
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
Failed: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of null
    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/stockmarket/portfolio/views/add-report-modal/add-report-modal.component.spec.ts:127:35
    at ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:391:1)
    at AsyncTestZoneSpec.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js.AsyncTestZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:714:1)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:286:1)
    at ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:390:1)
    at Zone../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:150:1)
```

I noticed when I run `ng-test` none of the actual animations work. When I tried it with a simple `div` and `ngIf`, the test passes, but fails when I use angular material.

I tried adding console.log to see if the element(`.gain-or-loss-required-error-message`) really is there, but it's just null. None of the animations work too, is this normal?

I remember in another project we were using bootstrap, and my tests were clicking buttons and displaying the correct error messages, it wasn't very complicated, there were even animations firing as my tests were running. Sorry, maybe I'm just missing something. I also tried importing `BrowserAnimationsModule` in my `TestBed imports`, because I thought maybe the reason I couldn't pick up the element was that the animations weren't firing but it didn't really do anything. Sorry, but what am I missing?

Comment: Can you share the TestBed configuration?

Comment: Hi, I have edited the question and it now includes the test bed configuration.

Comment: What happens when you use the NoopAnimationsModule in your tests?

Comment: It still gives the same error. Just a question, are animations supposed to firing when running `ng test` ?

Comment: Animations are not necessary...hence the NoopAnimationsModule